# java How do I convert double to string directly?

Tags: java, string, double

I want to convert double to string.
If I use Double.toString or String.valueOf it gives someting awful like 5e-10 or something like that.

if i have x = 0.00000032 i want to have string "0.00000032", simply.

I did it in a long way and I want to know whether there is a better (shorter) way to do it.

```
            szText += String.format("%.20f", dOutput);

            iZeros = 0;
            for(int i=szText.length() - 1; i>=0; i--)
            {
                if(szText.charAt(i) == '0')
                    ++iZeros;
                else break;
            }

            szText = szText.substring(0, szText.length() - iZeros);
```

Comment: scientific notation is not such a bad choice for numbers like 0.000000032. It's definately more readable.

Comment: I believe.
But let's say that for my needs this notation is undesirable :)

Comment: 0.00000032 *is* 3.2e-7.  There's nothing wrong with that representation.  It is not "something awful".  It is something accurate, efficient, and useful.

Comment: `new BigDecimal(double).toString()` will get you the precise value stored in the `double`, without secretly rounding for you...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's probably better choices, but you could use something like...

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(100);

double x = 0.00000032d;
System.out.println(x);
System.out.println(nf.format(x));
```

Which outputs

```
3.2E-7
0.00000032
```

You might want to play around with the `maximumFractionDigits` property to you specific needs...

Answer (score 1):

This is the prime use case for the [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class.

You'll want something along the lines of

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
String output = formatter.format(input);
```

The default behaviour of `DecimalFormat` is to round the fraction part to one decimal place. To change that, use MadProgrammer's solution of setting `formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(100)` or something like that.

Comment: What version of Java?  I basically plugged your code (two lines) to the end of my posted example (replacing `input` with `x`), maybe I did something wrong...

Comment: 1.7 here.. sorry it took so long, didn't have java on this machine!

Comment: Okay, tried Java 7 and 8. `0.00000032` prints `0`, `7.50000000000000000000000000000` prints `7.5`, could be a locality issue...

Comment: Curiouser still. Probably worthy of its own question!

Comment: Yep. Problem is the default value of `getMaximumFractionDigits()` is 1.  Will update answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
BigDecimal.valueOf(value).setScale(decimalLimit, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toPlainString()
```